# Passing Action Parameter to SchTasks in Macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I am trying to find a way to create a task in my task scheduler that would run on the mentioned below dates and that would execute a powershell with commands

```
strCommand = "schtasks /create /tn HasanChTesst /tr PowerShell.exe /sc weekly /d wed /st 13:00:00"
Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WsShell.Run (strCommand)
```

I have tried adding the parameters next to powershell as follows and i am getting a compilation error

```
strCommand = "schtasks /create /tn HasanChTesst /tr "PowerShell.exe Out-File Hello.txt"  /sc weekly /d wed /st 13:00:00"
Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WsShell.Run (strCommand)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this ?

Thank you

Note: i know that i can run powershell directly .. however i want to run task scheduler and let the scheduler run my powershell with parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not try this at home... See below why:**:

The usage of double quotes - `""` is needed, in order to escape the single quote `"`:

```
Sub WithParams()

    Dim command As String
    Dim wsShell As Object

    command = "schtasks /create /tn HasanChTesst /tr ""PowerShell.exe Out-File Hello.txt""  /sc weekly /d wed /st 13:00:00"
    Set wsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsShell.Run (command)

End Sub
```

**Because then you will need this:**

And in order to remove the task from the scheduled tasks, this is the code:

```
Sub RemoveTask()

    Dim wsShell As Object
    Set wsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsShell.Run ("powershell -noexit Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName ""HasanChTesst""")

End Sub
```

Comment: That was great, can you check my reply below ?

Comment: @HC - The `.FindAll()` probably does not work in the terminal (just guessing here). Give it a try with a new question.