# How to use Task Scheduler to run a macro in powerpoint?

Tags: vba, cmd, powerpoint, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run a VBA macro called test in a PowerPoint called Presentation1 daily by using Windows Task Scheduler. I set up the action with the program/script being `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"`

In the "Add Arguments" area I put:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE" /M "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Presentation1.pptm" "test"`

However, the only thing that shows is this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56600680/passing-action-parameter-to-schtasks-in-macro-vba/56601541#56601541

Answer (score 0):

If you turn the macro-enabled presentation into an add-in and run the VBA from an AutoOpen macro (also in the add-in), then all you have to worry about with task scheduler is starting PowerPoint: [How can I get my code to run automatically when a presentation opens?](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00741_How_can_I_get_my_code_to_run_automatically_when_a_presentation_opens-.htm)